# i want to repeat text file but it repeats and skips every 2nd line

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

i want to copy the text file and print in on standard output but it skips for every second line

```
with open("translation.txt") as f:
   line = f.readlines()

i=0
while i <len(line):
   print line[i]
   i=i+1
```

expected output

```
one eins
two zwei
three drei
four vier
```

actual output

```
one eins

two zwei

three drei

four vier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` adds a new line. Add a trailing comma:

```
print line[i],
```

This suppresses the newline.

Your whole program can be reduced to these lines:

```
with open("translation.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

I recommend to you to use Python 3. If you have to use Python 2 add this as the first line in your program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now you can use the `print` function in Python 2 and 3:

```
print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, the `print` statement prints an entire line, including a newline character, so the next time it is called the output will be on the next line. You can avoid this by adding a comma at the end of the statement, e.g.:

```
print line[i],
```